# Group and collapse <a> elements by class in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This question made my mind really busy.

I have a set of  tags like below

```
<a class='c1'>1</a>
<a class='c2'>2</a>
<a class='c3'>3</a>
<a class='c1'>4</a>
<a class='c1'>5</a>
<a class='c3'>6</a>
<a class='c2'>7</a>
```

What I need to do is to start from above and group elements together by class so that I can add a collapse to the elements. so the final results should be like this:

```
<div class='collapse'>
 <a class='c1'>1</a>
 <a class='c1'>4</a>
 <a class='c1'>5</a>
</div>
<div class='collapse'>
 <a class='c2'>2</a>
 <a class='c2'>7</a>
</div>
<div class='collapse'>
 <a class='c3'>3</a>
 <a class='c3'>6</a>
</div>
```

I have tried JS scripts with tones of variable that is really hacky and does not work. Is there a simple and clean way to do this?

thanks.

Comment: What is your JS so far? Why you cant modify original HTML? Is there any parent container for provided links?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way

```js
for(let i = 1; i<=3; i++){
    let tags = document.querySelectorAll(`.c${i}`);
    let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.classList = 'collapse';
    tags.forEach(tag =>{
        div.appendChild(tag);
    });
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
/* CSS just to demonstrate */
.collapse {
  margin-block: 1rem;
  border: blue solid 3px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<a class='c1'>1</a>
<a class='c2'>2</a>
<a class='c3'>3</a>
<a class='c1'>4</a>
<a class='c1'>5</a>
<a class='c3'>6</a>
<a class='c2'>7</a>
```

Comment: Wow this is fantastic thanks very much. Just a quick question, is there a way to keep the first element out and add the rest as sub-elements?

Comment: can you explain more i didn't understand, you mean first div as main container and the rest div's as sub content?

Comment: yes (my intention is to have the first element with a + on the left and when clicking on it, all sub-elements being shown). Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

I'd group them before appending to get more control over each separate element

This way you can eg add an `+` to the first child as OP suggested

- Get all the elements
- [Group them on `className`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)
- For each part, create a `div` where you `appendChild` all the `<a>`'s
- Append the `<div>`

```js
const all = [ ...document.querySelectorAll('a') ].reduce((p, c) => {
    (p[c.className] = p[c.className] || []).push(c);
    return p;
}, {});

for (let groupKey in all) {
    var e = document.createElement('div');
    e.classList.add('collapse');
    
    // Optionally: Add '+' to first child
    all[groupKey][0].innerHTML += ' +';
    
    all[groupKey].forEach(ee => e.appendChild(ee));
    document.body.append(e)
}
```

```css
.collapse { border: 1px solid red; display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
```

```html
<a class='c1'>1</a>
<a class='c2'>2</a>
<a class='c3'>3</a>
<a class='c1'>4</a>
<a class='c1'>5</a>
<a class='c3'>6</a>
<a class='c2'>7</a>
```